# Azure Marketplace currently cannot deploy Sitecore

Tags: azure, installation, sitecore

I am connected to the Azure account on which Sitecore has already been deployed. I removed it.
Now, I try to deploy a clean Sitecore. I have an XML free trial, but as soon as I click on *Configure required settings*, I have an error.

I choose 'Sitecore Experience Cloud', then I fill the input: Ressource group ( I tried with an existing one and a new one). And I clicked on *Configure required settings*, then I have the error:

> Important Notice:
>
> Marketplace cannot currently deploy to resource groups that contain certain characters in their name, for example underscore, due to Microsoft naming rules for Azure resources.
>
> Marketplace currently cannot deploy Sitecore in the first try of a fresh login session, Please retry on the same login session if there is no Submitting for deployment or Deployment in progress notification message after you started a new deployment.

If I continue to fill all the inputs, the next button is disabled event if I filled all the inputs.

I would like to complete the Sitecore website setup.

Comment: I tried with a new Azure account, and I have the same error. Thus it is not dues to the previous error.

Answer (score 0):

When Sitecore Azure fails to deploy
Restart ASP.NET.->Clear the browser cache.-> try with different browser

Investigate the Sitecore logs in the Sitecore Deployment server environment for errors.

Remove the instances from the environment and deploy again.

After deploying, configure the $(dataFolder)\AzurePackages(хх)Azure\SitecoreWebSite subfolder as the document root of an IIS web site, and diagnose that site.

Temporarily set the mode attribute of the /configuration/system.web/customErrors element in the web.config file to Off.
You may also refer to the suggestion mentioned in this article:  have you referred to this article https://www.valtech.com/en-in/insights/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-sitecore-9-on-microsoft-azure-marketplace-module/

Comment: I tried with another browser, same results.
I have removed all the previous instances (from the beginning).
I tried with resource group name: buzzsitecoredev. I also tried with simple name: aaaaa

The deployment even does not start!
Here is a print screen of the error:
![Printscreen Error in Azure Sitecore experience](http://ns3075290.ip-217-182-194.eu:8080/stitecoreexperience_azure.JPG).